# Custom error messages for standard errors in Cognos 8

Tags: cognos

Our Cognos 8 application has an error affecting many users:

http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/6849/aoeu.png

CM-REQ-4158
The search path ... is invalid.

We know how to fix this problem (it's a browser configuration issue) but the error message is not helpful. Also, users will get this issue if they upgrade IE.

SO

Is it possible for us to modify this error message so it is more useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the only way you'll be able to hone in on those messages is to use the Language Development Kit (LDK).. I'm sure you can edit them by hand, but I don't think it's worth it.